# How to communicate with a Web API within container from an ASP.NET Core Web application on localhost

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

There is a web application which is running within a container on my local machine. This web application is accessible through url: "http://myapp:3030", and on my local machine I can browse the app. The myapp APIs are also accessible from postman using "http://myapp:3030/api" url.

Using aspnet.core httpclient, I want to communicate with "http://myapp:3030/api" (within container) from an asp.net core application which is running on my local machine, localhost:5001 (outside container):

```
using var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
HttpResponseMessage httpResponse;
   
try
{
    httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri("http://myapp:3030/api/dosomething"), content);
    httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
catch (HttpRequestException e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    throw;
}
```

The request above fails with "No such host is known." exception, while the same request though postman works properly. How can I communicate with a web api within container from an aspnet.core web application on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you started your container with `--name myapp -p 5001:3030`, then Postman (and your browser, and other code on your host, not in a container) would reach **`localhost:5001`** routes, and [other services in the same Docker network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) would need to use `myapp:3030`.

Without a shared network you get such DNS errors.

For consistency, try not remapping the ports while debugging local containers.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I am mapping `3030:3000`, in fact `http://myapp:3030` works as a public url for `myapp` within container so, I can browse the app or access its APIs through postman. But, using the same url `http://myapp:3030` inside my asp.net core application (outside container) the `localhost:5001` cannot communicate with `http://myapp:3030`

Comment: It's not clear what's running on port 5001, but you'd need to use localhost:3030 from any code/app/browser on your host